# How to separate index.html and assets in webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

i want to have the following build folder structure:

- /build/index.html
- /build/static/bundlename.js
- /build/static/bundlename.css
- /build/static/img/*
- /build/static/fonts/*

How can i achieve this? I have figured out this by addition /static prefix to bundlename itself for webpack normal build itself. But when i run this config in webpack-dev-server it doesn't server files by /static/ path.

I use file-loader and url-loader for fonts, how i can change their path as well? THey appear in /build root and i want them in /static/fonts folder.

I use html-webpack-plugin to generate index.html and append styles link (have no idea why webpack want to add them from js by default, it's crazyness, just as option i can see, but not as default way)

I run webpack by gulp.

You can see my config here. 
https://github.com/rantiev/template-angular

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `output.path`:

```
output: {
    path: "build/static",
    publicPath: "/static/"
}
```

and change path from `index.html` to `../index.html` in html-webpack-plugin

Comment: It works in webpack build but doesn't work when i run it with webpack-dev-sever.  Neither by opening / or /static webpack-dev-server gives nothing.

I added publicPath, change index.html path to go with ../, added publicPath + historyApiFallback to webpack-dev-server. The problem is that i can't make it work with devserver not webpack simple build.

Have you tried this by yourself with webpack-dev-server? Please provide your settings if so. Cool idea but doesn't work for me. Might did something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not using webpack-dev-server, anyway I tried to make it works but lo luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You have `output.path`, `output.publicPath` & `output.filename`
([see here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path))
`output.path` option determines the location on disk the files are written

In your case you want `path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')`
That'll put the `index.html` from the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` into your `build` directory.

`output.filename`

> Specifies the name of each output file on disk. You must not specify
>   an absolute path here! The output.path option determines the location
>   on disk the files are written. filename is used solely for naming the
>   individual files.

In your case you'll want `filename: './static/bundlename.js'`
That'll put the bundled JS into the static directory

To get the CSS into your static directory you'll need the [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin). Once you get that going you'll want to put something in your webpack plugins like `new ExtractTextPlugin('static/bundlename.css')`

For your images & fonts you can specify in your loaders something like this:

```
{
    test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$/
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'font location here')
    ],
    loader: 'url',
    query: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: 'static/fonts/[name].[ext]'
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'image location here')
    ],
    loader: 'file',
    query: {
      limit: 10000,
      minetype: 'image/svg+xml',
      name: 'static/img/[name].[ext]'
    }
  }
```

`output.publicPath` specifies the public URL address of the output files when referenced in a browser. You might want to try
`publicPath: http://localhost:8000/` and look at this [Webpack "OTS parsing error" loading fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133808/webpack-ots-parsing-error-loading-fonts/34133809#34133809)