# Preserving folder structure in output directory with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following folder structure:

```
/index.html
/app/index.tsx
```

After bundling with webpack, I would like to have the following ouput directory with the bundle.js injected into the index.html

```
/dist/index.html
/dist/app/bundle.js
/dist/app/bundle.js.map
```

I have the following webpack configuration

```
var webpack = require("webpack")
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = [
    {
        entry: "./app/index",
        output: {
            path: "./dist/app",
            filename: "bundle.js"
        },
        devtool: "source-map",
        resolve: {
            extensions: ["", ".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                "filename": "./index.html",
                "template": "html!./index.html"
            })
        ],
        module: {
            loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        output: {
            path: "./dist",
            filename: "bundle.js"
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                "filename": "./index.html",
                "template": "html!./index.html"
            })
        ]    
    }
]
```

It seems to work fine, but the script bundle.js is not injected into the index.html as expected. The HtmlWebpackPlugin is supposed to do this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your `./index.html` contain the templating `HtmlWebpackPlugin` expects as in their base template? It won't write the script section otherwise.

Comment: Yes. I can rewrite the config where the script gets injected but the folder structure does not get preserved

Comment: If you not using webpack-dev-server you can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106276/how-to-separate-index-html-and-assets-in-webpack-dev-server/36106310?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to [WebpackHtmlPlugin issue #234](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/issues/234).

From https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath

> `output.publicPath` The publicPath specifies the public URL address of
>   the output files when referenced in a browser.

What you can do is to add the `'app'` folder name to the output filename:

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: "app/[name]-[hash].js",
    path: "dist",
    publicPath: ""
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       "template": "html!./index.html"
    }),
  ],
}
```

Comment: This was exactly it. I didn't know how to word the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML Bundler plugin](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin) for Webpack can read template files in a [source directory](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin#option-entry-path) and save compiled HTML files with the same structure in the output directory.

For example, there are templates in the `src/views/` source directory:

```
src/views/index.html
src/views/about/index.html
src/views/news/sport/index.html
src/views/news/sport/hockey/index.html
src/views/news/sport/football/index.html
...
```

We want to have the same folder structure in the `dist/` directory:

```
dist/index.html
dist/about/index.html
dist/news/sport/index.html
dist/news/sport/hockey/index.html
dist/news/sport/football/index.html
...
```

Just install the html-bundler-webpack-plugin:

```
npm install html-bundler-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Add the plugin in the Webpack config:

```js
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: 'src/views/', // the template directory
    }),
  ],
};
```

All templates from the `src/views/` directory will be compiled and saved in the `dist/` directory with the same structure.
All source script and style files referenced in HTML will be processed automatically.