# Webpack 4 - Preserve folder structure for bundles

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack.config.js

I'm can't preserve folder structure for my output bundles.

I tried to use `[path]` [placeholder](https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils#interpolatename) but it doesn't work.
There is similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122972/preserving-folder-structure-in-output-directory-with-webpack) but it does not answer my question.

I'm using: Webpack 4.28.4 and Node v10.15.0.

Entry folder structure:

```
src
|  
+-- blog
|  |
|  +-- index.js
|  
+-- index.js
```

webpack.config.js:

```
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js',
    blog: './src/blog/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[path][name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
```

On output I got:

```
dist
|  
+-- [path]blog.c63bf8952b90c5e5ba3e.js
|  
+-- [path]main.9ad0ffac44f9e88f76ce.js
```

But I expect:

```
dist
|  
+-- blog
|  |
|  +-- blog.c63bf8952b90c5e5ba3e.js
|  
+-- main.9ad0ffac44f9e88f76ce.js
```

Note: I used `[name]` placeholder to identify files but finally I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody looking solution

Only one that i found is using path as entry name(maybe exist some plugin). like in answer above.

I made simply array transform which allows me transform me ts path to entries.

```js
const entries = [
    "admin/ts/form.ts",
    "path/to/some/file.ts"
].reduce((acc, path) => {
    const key =
        path.split("/")
        .map(part => part === "ts" ? "js" : part)
        .join("/")
        .replace(/.ts|.tsx$/, "")
    return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: "./static_src/" + path
    }
}, {})

console.log(entries)
```

and now in your webpack config you can:

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: entries,
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static_compiled'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This help me a LOT when I did not want to bundling and keep the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `name` of your entry chunk to be a path within your output dir that you'd like to see when it is output, that will do the trick for you.

For example, if you renamed your blog entry to `blog/blog` like below, when webpack generates the bundle and outputs it to the output directory, since the filename is `blog/blog`, the result will be `dist/blog/blog.[contenthash].js`. The other file will still be `main.[contenthash].js`.

This should do the trick for you:

```
 `entry: {
    main: './src/index.js',
    'blog/blog': './src/blog/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }`
```