# Unable to load fonts

Tags: html, css, webpack, fonts

I get the following error when I try loading fonts into the [Spectacle boilerplate](http://formidable.com/open-source/spectacle/#layout-tags):

> Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/assets/fonts/Overpass-Bold.ttf
>   OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

I've added a format type, and am loading my styles via a style tag in my html file.

Also, I thought that maybe it's a webpack issue, so I've also added this into the webpack config file:

```js
{
  test: /\.ttf$/,
  loader: "url-loader?limit=100000&mimetype=application/font-ttf"
}
```

```html
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Bold";
    src: url("./assets/fonts/Overpass-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Regular";
    src: url("./assets/fonts/Overpass-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Light";
    src: url("./assets/fonts/Overpass-Light.ttf") format('truetype');
  }
</style>
```

Could anyone guide me as to what could be wrong and I'm not able to load my fonts?

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, is that the correct file path? Just want to make sure you meant to say ./ instead of ../

Comment: Yes, it is the correct path. See in my console I see that the browser tries to get it here:  http://localhost:3000/assets/fonts/Overpass-Bold.ttf and that matches my folder structure

Comment: Gotcha. Just wanted to double check. I know that has happened to me before with xampp.

Comment: thanks for double checking though, could have been the issue but doesn't seem so..

Comment: @font-face {
    font-family: "Light";
    src: url("../assets/fonts/Overpass-Light.ttf") format('truetype');
  }

Comment: Synatax Error ..Change

Comment: OTS parsing errors indicate the font file was loaded (so the path/URL works) but the file itself is invalid/corrupt and can't be parsed. A common reason for this is an incorrect file transfer via bundlers like webpack. See also these SO posts ["Webpack "OTS parsing error" loading fonts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133808/webpack-ots-parsing-error-loading-fonts), ["Webpack 5 issues with fonts getting Failed to decode & OTS parsing error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839232/webpack-5-issues-with-fonts-getting-failed-to-decode-ots-parsing-error)

Answer (score 0):

this is my code for the font face :

```
@font-face 
{
  font-family: "BebasNeue_Regular";
  src: url("../../Resource/Font/Bebas Neue/.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../../Resource/Font/Bebas Neue/.woff") format("woff"), url("../../Resource/Font/Bebas Neue/.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../../Resource/Font/Bebas Neue/.svg#BebasNeue_Regular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

this is the callback :

```
h1
{
    font family: 'BebasNeue_Regular';
}
```

there are some problems : 
1. maybe your browser doesn't support the font file -> thats why i use some src url for callback.
2. are you really sure the file name is correct ?.
3. if it is, try to access the font url with your browser, is it work or missing.
4. there are some issues with firefox that doesn't render font during the local launch.

Answer (score 0):

- Check that your web server has permission to read the folder containing the fonts and the font files themselves. Also check the files that their permissions are not "forbidden" -and should be readable by your web server user (-or "everyone").
- Make sure that the URL paths to these fonts are correct; you can test this also with a background image URL in the same CSS file to test relative paths.
- If the above is fine, then there may be something wrong with a specific font file, or your web server may not be transferring the  binary data correctly. The latter may be caused when you override the default web-server behavior and stream the data through some other means.
- Try the above with a web-font that you know will work, like "FontAwesome"; if that fails then the only thing left is that the binary data is being delivered incorrectly - so maybe extra "white-space" is prepended or appended --which happens quite easily with an embedding language, like PHP.
- If it is a problem as stated in the last point above, it is easily fixed by clearing your output buffer -before -and -after delivering the font-data. In PHP the output buffer can be cleaned (and checked) with: `ob_get_clean()`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what everyone is saying:

In my case, the font file name had a `-` in it, as a separator between words. I tried everything to make the browser load it but it wouldn't, the only thing that eventually worked was removing the dash from the file name, and then it worked! (Tested on Firefox and Edge)

I would go further and advise to have the font file name have no special characters or spaces, etc.

What didn't work:

```
cairo-bold.tff
```

What did work:

```
cairoBold.tff
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your CSS Syntax is not Proper

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Bold";
    src: url("../assets/fonts/Overpass-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');
  }
```

Try Now
Your path For the Font is not Proper, You Have added one dot insted of two dot