# Fonts don't display with Sass, React, create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, sass, font-face

I'm working on a React project made with create-react-app.

I'm using Sass and the sass files transpile correctly.

I have local fonts that I want to embed in the app.

I use the @font-face rule correctly, I believe, in my sass file. Here it is for one of the fonts:

```
/* poppins-200 - latin_latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-display: swap; /* Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display for other options. */
  font-family: 'someName';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: url('/assets/fonts/poppins-v20-latin_latin-ext-200.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('/assets/fonts/poppins-v20-latin_latin-ext-200.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('/assets/fonts/poppins-v20-latin_latin-ext-200.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('/assets/fonts/poppins-v20-latin_latin-ext-200.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('/assets/fonts/poppins-v20-latin_latin-ext-200.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('/assets/fonts/poppins-v20-latin_latin-ext-200.svg#Poppins') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

This is my sass class, which I assign to a `<p>` element:

```
.someClassName{
  font-family: 'someName';
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #090909;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:  0px;
                 }
```

but the `<p>` element does not appear in the app in the correct font.

I get this type of error message in Chrome's web developer tools console for each font:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3002/assets/fonts/poppins-v20-latin_latin-ext-200.woff2
```

and this one in Firefox:

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "someName" style:normal weight:200 stretch:100 src index:1) source: http://localhost:3002/assets/fonts/poppins-v20-latin_latin-ext-200.woff2
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "someName" style:normal weight:200 stretch:100 src index:2) source: http://localhost:3002/assets/fonts/poppins-v20-latin_latin-ext-200.woff
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "someName" style:normal weight:200 stretch:100 src index:3) source: http://localhost:3002/assets/fonts/poppins-v20-latin_latin-ext-200.ttf
downloadable font: no supported format found (font-family: "someName" style:normal weight:200 stretch:100 src index:5) source: (end of source list)
```

It doesn't matter which font I use. I have tried three unrelated fonts all downloaded from Google Fonts and the problem is the same each time.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: "Failed to decode downloaded font" usually indicates a font got corrupted at some point. Some bundlers might copy files in a wrong transfer mode (e.g ascii insted of binary). Check also if there are any optimisations activated (additional file compression, subsetting fonts)

Comment: how should I check whether the bundler (webpack) is copying a file in the wrong transfer mode? also how should I check for optimisations?

Comment: Maybe this answer might help ["Webpack 5 issues with fonts getting Failed to decode & OTS parsing error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839232/webpack-5-issues-with-fonts-getting-failed-to-decode-ots-parsing-error)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I have sorted the problem out.

It turns out that apps created using `create-react-app` can deal with `.scss` files out of the box.

This is what I had been doing:

1. I was editing the `.scss` file and getting the following script to convert it to a `.css` file on the fly:

```json
"changeSassToCSS": "sass --watch src/scss:src/assets/css"
```

2. I was importing the `.css` file into my `index.js` and `App.js` files

This is what I did to solve the problem:

1. Dumped the `.css` file
2. Dumped the script that transpired from `.scss` to `.css`
3. Imported the `.scss` file into my `index.js` and `App.js` files.

Answer (score 0):

Also I had used my own name for a font family in the .scss file where I had used the @font-face rule.

Instead of this:

```
/* poppins-200 - latin_latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-display: swap; /* Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display for other options. */
  font-family: 'someName';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: url('/assets/fonts/
```

which made the browser use some default font instead of Poppins

I should have written this:

```
/* poppins-200 - latin_latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-display: swap; /* Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display for other options. */
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: url('/assets/fonts/
```

Comment: Do you know for sure that you successfully imported the SCSS file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have now sorted out the problem. See my answer to my own question (above)