# Fonts are not loaded on IOS with @font-face

Tags: ios, next.js, fonts, tailwind-css

I have 3 fonts in my **Next.js 14.0.4** project which are stored in `public/fonts/` folder.

I'm aware such question already exists on StackOverflow but it didn't help me.

**NOTE:** Only Avenir is being used on the site for now. Avenir has **.ttf**, **.woff**, and **.woff2** extensions

I'm using **TailwindCSS** for styling and fonts are set up there in a following way:

```js
theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                capitanaBlack: ['Capitana Black', 'sans-serif'],
                capitanaBold: ['Capitana Bold', 'sans-serif'],
                capitanaLight: ['Capitana Light', 'sans-serif'],
                capitanaMedium: ['Capitana Medium', 'sans-serif'],
                capitanaRegular: ['Capitana Regular', 'sans-serif'],
                capitanaSemiBold: ['Capitana SemiBold', 'sans-serif'],
                capitanaThin: ['Capitana Thin', 'sans-serif'],
                avenirBlack: ['Avenir Black', 'sans-serif'],
...
```

After that I call font in **css**:

```
.className {
   @apply font-avenirBlack;
}
```

**[Here](https://pastebin.com/az0iLdqf)** is **`fonts.css`** which is located in `@/app/` directory

and here is a photo of fonts in the folder:

[image]

Fonts work fine on desktop version and on android but not a one font is loaded on IOS both in Chrome or Safari

Comment: Please check your devtools network tab for loaded fonts. Quite likely it works on desktop due to a locally installed avenir font. So triple check your paths and also the console for parsing orf CORS errors

Comment: @herrstrietzel network tab shows me http 304 so it means that it is loaded successfuly. It might be another reason

Comment: @herrstrietzel I outputted `console.log` to check whether font is loaded or not using `document.fonts.ready.then(...)` and received true

Comment: Unfortunately 304 can be a bit deceptive it just means your file hasn't changed since the last caching. The same applies to `document.fonts.ready` – it's not reliable and may incorrectly return true on many occasions. Try to open and inspect your page in private mode. Then check select an element with "Avenir" applied to and switch to the computed style tab – ideally you would see something like "Avenir Black" network resource if not you should see info in the network tab.

Comment: Besides try to simplify your `@font-face` rules. While being correct - introducing  a new `font-family` for each weight or style is likely to cause more mapping problems.  You also don't  need the first `src` property as it is overridden by the following one. Try to strip the `local` src completely – it has been quite error prone in the past. If it's  actually a iOS related issue and you're running on windows you may install a virtual OS via virtualBox and try to reproduce your error in a linux environment like mint running "Web/epiphany" or midori – allowing you to use a webkit inspector.

Comment: @herrstrietzel It happened to be that the problem is related to the font itself. I tried another font and it is displayed correctly

Comment: Strange: In this case you should have seen a log like "OTS parsing error". Corruption of font files can happen with unsuitable loader settings in bundlers like webpack

Comment: @herrstrietzel yes, as expected new font doesn't work too :) Don't really understand what the problem is related to and how to solve it now

Comment: I have the sneaky suspicion some bundling or upload process corrupts the fonts e.g by transferring the fonts not as binary files. If you're using webpack see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839232/webpack-5-issues-with-fonts-getting-failed-to-decode-ots-parsing-error)

Comment: @herrstrietzel the real problem was in `fonts.css`. I changed from `"Avenir Black"` to `"Avenir-Black"` and everything works now!