Summernote and Webpack font issues
I'm trying to use Summernote and Webpack together in a Typescript project. (No React or Vue or Angular or anything.) I can get it to create the editor, but the icons for the control strip show up as unhelpful small boxes.

Error messages:

Chrome says: Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:4000/bc4806b8745111d7ee9d.woff2
Firefox says: downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "summernote" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1) source: http://localhost:4000/bc4806b8745111d7ee9d.woff2
Safari doesn't say anything about fonts, but the issue happens there too.

There's a post here from about 4.5 years ago (How to fix "downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer") that says the fonts might be invalid or corrupted, so I grabbed new copies (no luck), uninstalled and reinstalled summernote via npm (no luck) and then switched to yarn (no luck), and tried running them through a converter (which didn't complain but also didn't fix the problem). https://fontdrop.info/ is also perfectly happy with it, so I really think it's not a font validity issue.
I checked the other Summernote-and-Webpack threads here and unfortunately they're all giving different error messages than the ones I'm seeing.
Any idea what else might be going on?
Here's my webpack config file:
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "postcss-loader" },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              implementation: require("sass"),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "images",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "font",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    alias: {
      jquery: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery"),
      jQuery: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery"),
    },
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Ecrivaine",
      template: "src/custom.html",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "bundle.css",
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      CodeMirror: "codemirror",
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin(), new TerserPlugin()],
  },
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 600,
    poll: 2000,
    ignored: "**/node_modules",
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 4000,
  },
};

And package.json:
{
  "name": "ecrivaine",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The online ebook editor",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "develop": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ebook",
    "editor",
    "typescript",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "author": "Colin Fredericks",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/codemirror": "^5.60.15",
    "@types/summernote": "^0.8.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "codemirror": "^5.65.16",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss": "^8.0.1",
    "summernote": "^0.8.20",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.29",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.75.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  }
}

And here's the very simple part where I'm actually calling Summernote
$(".summernote").summernote({
  height: 300,
  codemirror: {
    theme: "monokai",
  },
});

If you see "ecrivaine" that's the name of the project.

A decoding error usually means the font got corrupted in this case quiite likely due to the webpack bundling process. Have a look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839232/webpack-5-issues-with-fonts-getting-failed-to-decode-ots-parsing-error

@herrstrietzel Hallelujah it works. Thank you so much. Put it in as an answer and I'll hit "accept".

glad it helped! But it makes more sense If you could post your final config code as an answer. webpack still seems to be quite annoying in this regards - so it could certainly be helpful for others with a similar setup

Many thanks to @herrstrietzel for the answer. Here's what my final webpack.config.js looks like:
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "postcss-loader" },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              implementation: require("sass"),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    alias: {
      jquery: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery"),
      jQuery: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery"),
    },
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Ecrivaine",
      template: "src/custom.html",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "bundle.css",
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      CodeMirror: "codemirror",
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin(), new TerserPlugin()],
  },
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 600,
    poll: 2000,
    ignored: "**/node_modules",
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 4000,
  },
};

If anyone has issues with the menus on Summernote not working in this setup, that's actually a collision with Bootstrap 5 instead of with Webpack.
