# Importing webfont causes 100s of link/style tags in HTML

Tags: webpack

I have the following line in a SCSS file which a lot of other files imports

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700);
```

This results in 100s of these lines

[image]

And these warnings in the console

[image]

I have tried the solution described here [Webpack "OTS parsing error" loading fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133808/webpack-ots-parsing-error-loading-fonts), but have been unable to correct this

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked if you've got the right path for **@font-face** declaration? That may lead to this error.

Comment: I don;t even use a @font-face, rather, I just use the Lato font directly in my `font-family` attribute. Also, the font is applied correctly, wouldn't this not be the case if the wrong path was being used?

Comment: So the font applies, but throws the warnings?

Comment: Maybe is gonna help, it seems to work in other browsers but it throws this error in Chrome...


  [1]: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=545924