# Chrome and Firefox unable to parse and decode font

Tags: fonts, webpack

I'm using Hapi on the backend and React on the frontend. My webpack config specifies the following:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=public/ozregular.otf'}
  ]
},
```

The CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: OzRegular;
  src: url(/ozregular.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

The font works in Safari but in Chrome I get these errors:
[image: chrome errors]

And in firefox I get these errors:
[image: firefox errors]

I have tried the answers to the following stackoverflow question but it does not seem to be working: [Webpack "OTS parsing error" loading fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133808/webpack-ots-parsing-error-loading-fonts)

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get the font working in Chrome and Firefox?