# @import syntax inside css file not resolving font file

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I am working on a react application and trying to implement CSS + Fonts.

In my react component CSS file I have regular CSS and at the very top I import my mixins

```
@import '../../mixins.css';
/*CSS*/
```

Inside my mixin file I have

```
mixin.css

@font-face {
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Black';
  src: url("./SourceSansPro-Black.ttf") format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Webpack throws an error

```
Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./SourceSansPro-Black.ttf
```

This is my webpack config module loadres

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app')
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/styles'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/components')
        ],
        loader: combineLoaders([
          {
            loader: 'style'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css',
            query: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              localIdentName: '[folder]__[local]--[hash:base64:10]'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss'
          }
        ])
      },
      // Font Definitions
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/assets/fonts')
        ],
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 50000,
          mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
          name: './fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

and the postcss

```
postcss: (_webpack) => {
    return [
      require('postcss-import')({
        addDependencyTo: _webpack,
        path: [ 'styles', 'components'],
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app'),
        skipDuplicates: true
      }),
      require('postcss-cssnext')()
    ];
  },
```

I dont' understand why the `url` isn't resolving correctly.

**UPDATE**
I have a `font.css` file that looks like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Bold';
  src: url('./SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular';
  src: url('./SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Light';
  src: url('./SourceSansPro-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I then import the `font.css` into a `mixins.css` file

```
@import '../fonts/fonts.css';
:root {
  --regular: {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}
```

Then in my react component I have this:

```
@import 'styles/mixins.css';

.regular {
  @apply --regular;
}
```

There is no error (or warning) that states any issues with loading the fonts via the `url()`.

`webpack.config`

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app')
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/assets/fonts'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/assets/styles'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/components')
        ],
        loader: combineLoaders([
          {
            loader: 'style',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css',
            query: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              localIdentName: '[folder]__[local]--[hash:base64:10]'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'resolve-url',
            query: {
              sourceMap: true,
              silent: false,
              fail: true,
              keepQuery: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss',
            query: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ])
      },
      // Font Definitions
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/assets/fonts')
        ],
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 100000,
          mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
          name: './fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

An interesting thing is that if I use the `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin` on the CSS the above works, the fonts get rendered. If I do it this way the tradeOff is there is no CSS hot reloading.

Any suggestions on how to get the fonts to load without the `extract-text plugin`?

Comment: It turns out that if I set `sourceMap: false` in the css-loader, I can get hot-reloading with fonts working. But now I don't have sourcemap :)

Comment: This issue has been reported here: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/296

Comment: I found this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133808/webpack-ots-parsing-error-loading-fonts/34133809#34133809  this explains the issue and solution. Cheers!!