# Upgrading webpack version throws errors in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

> webpack 1

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import cssnano from 'cssnano'
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'
import config from '../config'
import _debug from 'debug'

const debug = _debug('app:webpack:config')
const paths = config.utils_paths
const {__DEV__, __PROD__, __TEST__} = config.globals

debug('Create configuration.')
const webpackConfig = {
  name: 'client',
  target: 'web',
  devtool: config.compiler_devtool,
  resolve: {
    root: [
      paths.client(),
      paths.shared()
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  module: {}
}
// ------------------------------------
// Entry Points
// ------------------------------------
const APP_ENTRY_PATHS = [
  'babel-polyfill',
  'whatwg-fetch',
  paths.client('main.js')
]

webpackConfig.entry = {
  app: __DEV__
    ? APP_ENTRY_PATHS.concat(`webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=${config.compiler_public_path}__webpack_hmr`)
    : APP_ENTRY_PATHS,
  vendor: config.compiler_vendor
}

// ------------------------------------
// Bundle Output
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.output = {
  filename: `[name].[${config.compiler_hash_type}].js`,
  path: paths.dist(),
  publicPath: config.compiler_public_path
}

// ------------------------------------
// Plugins
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(config.globals),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: paths.client('index.html'),
    hash: false,
    favicon: paths.client('static/favicon.ico'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: false,
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true
    },
    // NOTE: ADD ESRI / DOJO Default Configurations here ...
    dojoConfig: JSON.stringify({
    })
  })
]

if (__DEV__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for live development (HMR, NoErrors).')
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  )
} else if (__PROD__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for production (OccurenceOrder, Dedupe & UglifyJS).')
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  )
}

// Don't split bundles during testing, since we only want import one bundle
if (!__TEST__) {
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor']
    })
  )
}

// ------------------------------------
// Pre-Loaders
// ------------------------------------
/*
[ NOTE ]
We no longer use eslint-loader due to it severely impacting build
times for larger projects. `npm run lint` still exists to aid in
deploy processes (such as with CI), and it's recommended that you
use a linting plugin for your IDE in place of this loader.

If you do wish to continue using the loader, you can uncomment
the code below and run `npm i --save-dev eslint-loader`. This code
will be removed in a future release.

webpackConfig.module.preLoaders = [{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  loader: 'eslint',
  exclude: /node_modules/
}]

webpackConfig.eslint = {
  configFile: paths.base('.eslintrc'),
  emitWarning: __DEV__
}
*/

// ------------------------------------
// Loaders
// ------------------------------------
// JavaScript / JSON
webpackConfig.module.loaders = [{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel',
  query: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'recharts'],
    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
    env: {
      production: {
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  test: /\.json$/,
  loader: 'json'
}]

// ------------------------------------
// Style Loaders
// ------------------------------------
// We use cssnano with the postcss loader, so we tell
// css-loader not to duplicate minimization.
const BASE_CSS_LOADER = 'css?modules&sourceMap&-minimize'

// Add any packge names here whose styles need to be treated as CSS modules.
// These paths will be combined into a single regex.
const PATHS_TO_TREAT_AS_CSS_MODULES = [
  'flexboxgrid'
]

// If config has CSS modules enabled, treat this project's styles as CSS modules.
if (config.compiler_css_modules) {
  PATHS_TO_TREAT_AS_CSS_MODULES.push(
    paths.client().replace(/[\^\$\.\*\+\-\?\=\!\:\|\\\/\(\)\[\]\{\}\,]/g, '\\$&') // eslint-disable-line
  )
}

const isUsingCSSModules = !!PATHS_TO_TREAT_AS_CSS_MODULES.length
const cssModulesRegex = new RegExp(`(${PATHS_TO_TREAT_AS_CSS_MODULES.join('|')})`)

// Loaders for styles that need to be treated as CSS modules.
if (isUsingCSSModules) {
  const cssModulesLoader = [
    BASE_CSS_LOADER,
    'modules',
    'importLoaders=1',
    'localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  ].join('&')

  webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: cssModulesRegex,
    loaders: [
      'style',
      cssModulesLoader,
      'postcss',
      'sass?sourceMap'
    ]
  })

  webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: cssModulesRegex,
    loaders: [
      'style',
      cssModulesLoader,
      'postcss'
    ]
  })
}

// Loaders for files that should not be treated as CSS modules.
const excludeCSSModules = isUsingCSSModules ? cssModulesRegex : false
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: excludeCSSModules,
  loaders: [
    'style',
    BASE_CSS_LOADER,
    'postcss',
    'sass?sourceMap'
  ]
})
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: excludeCSSModules,
  loaders: [
    'style',
    BASE_CSS_LOADER,
    'postcss'
  ]
})

// ------------------------------------
// Style Configuration
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.sassLoader = {
  includePaths: paths.client('styles')
}

webpackConfig.postcss = [
  cssnano({
    autoprefixer: {
      add: true,
      remove: true,
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    },
    discardComments: {
      removeAll: true
    },
    discardUnused: false,
    mergeIdents: false,
    reduceIdents: false,
    safe: true,
    sourcemap: true
  })
]

// File loaders
/* eslint-disable */
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push(
  { test: /\.woff(\?.*)?$/,  loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
  { test: /\.woff2(\?.*)?$/, loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2' },
  { test: /\.otf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=font/opentype' },
  { test: /\.ttf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
  { test: /\.eot(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]' },
  { test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
  { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,    loader: 'url?limit=8192' }
)
/* eslint-enable */

/* Configure Webpack to ignore dojo modules */
webpackConfig.module.externals = [
  function(context, request, callback) {
    if (/^dojo/.test(request) ||
        /^dojox/.test(request) ||
        /^dijit/.test(request) ||
       /^esri/.test(request)
    ) {
        return callback(null, "amd " + request);
    }
    callback();
  }
];

// ------------------------------------
// Finalize Configuration
// ------------------------------------
// when we don't know the public path (we know it only when HMR is enabled [in development]) we
// need to use the extractTextPlugin to fix this issue:
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133808/webpack-ots-parsing-error-loading-fonts/34133809#34133809
if (!__DEV__) {
  debug('Apply ExtractTextPlugin to CSS loaders.')
  webpackConfig.module.loaders.filter((loader) =>
    loader.loaders && loader.loaders.find((name) => /css/.test(name.split('?')[0]))
  ).forEach((loader) => {
    const [first, ...rest] = loader.loaders
   loader.loader = ExtractTextPlugin.extract(first, rest.join('!'))
    Reflect.deleteProperty(loader, 'loaders')
  })

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[contenthash].css', {
      allChunks: true
    })
  )
}

export default webpackConfig
```

> webpack 3 (After upgrading)

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import cssnano from 'cssnano'
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'
import config from '../config'
import _debug from 'debug'

const debug = _debug('app:webpack:config')
const paths = config.utils_paths
const {__DEV__, __PROD__, __TEST__} = config.globals

debug('Create configuration.')
const webpackConfig = {
  name: 'client',
  target: 'web',
  devtool: config.compiler_devtool,
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      paths.client(),
      paths.shared(),
      "node_modules"
    ],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules:[]
  }
}
// ------------------------------------
// Entry Points
// ------------------------------------
const APP_ENTRY_PATHS = [
  'babel-polyfill',
  'whatwg-fetch',
  paths.client('main.js')
]

webpackConfig.entry = {
  app: __DEV__
    ? APP_ENTRY_PATHS.concat(`webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=${config.compiler_public_path}__webpack_hmr`)
    : APP_ENTRY_PATHS,
  vendor: config.compiler_vendor
}

// ------------------------------------
// Bundle Output
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.output = {
  filename: `[name].[${config.compiler_hash_type}].js`,
  path: paths.dist(),
  publicPath: config.compiler_public_path
}

// ------------------------------------
// Plugins
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(config.globals),
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: paths.client('index.html'),
    hash: false,
    favicon: paths.client('static/favicon.ico'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: true,
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true
    },
    // NOTE: ADD ESRI / DOJO Default Configurations here ...
    dojoConfig: JSON.stringify({
    })
  })
]

if (__DEV__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for live development (HMR, NoErrors).')
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  )
} else if (__PROD__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for production (OccurenceOrder, Dedupe & UglifyJS).')
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  )
}

// Don't split bundles during testing, since we only want import one bundle
if (!__TEST__) {
 webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor']
    })
  )
}

// ------------------------------------
// Pre-Loaders
// ------------------------------------
/*
[ NOTE ]
We no longer use eslint-loader due to it severely impacting build
times for larger projects. `npm run lint` still exists to aid in
deploy processes (such as with CI), and it's recommended that you
use a linting plugin for your IDE in place of this loader.

If you do wish to continue using the loader, you can uncomment
the code below and run `npm i --save-dev eslint-loader`. This code
will be removed in a future release.

webpackConfig.module.preLoaders = [{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  loader: 'eslint',
  exclude: /node_modules/
}]

webpackConfig.eslint = {
  configFile: paths.base('.eslintrc'),
  emitWarning: __DEV__
}
*/

// ------------------------------------
// Loaders
// ------------------------------------
// JavaScript / JSON
webpackConfig.module.rules = [{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [{
  loader:'babel-loader',
  query: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    plugins: ['babel-plugin-transform-runtime', 'recharts'],
    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
    env: {
      production: {
      }
    }
 }}]
}]

// ------------------------------------
// Style Loaders
// ------------------------------------
// We use cssnano with the postcss loader, so we tell
// css-loader not to duplicate minimization.
const BASE_CSS_LOADER = 'css?modules&sourceMap&-minimize'

// Add any packge names here whose styles need to be treated as CSS modules.
// These paths will be combined into a single regex.
const PATHS_TO_TREAT_AS_CSS_MODULES = [
'flexboxgrid'
]

// If config has CSS modules enabled, treat this project's styles as CSS modules.
if (config.compiler_css_modules) {
  PATHS_TO_TREAT_AS_CSS_MODULES.push(
    paths.client().replace(/[\^\$\.\*\+\-\?\=\!\:\|\\\/\(\)\[\]\{\}\,]/g, '\\$&') // eslint-disable-line
  )
}

const isUsingCSSModules = !!PATHS_TO_TREAT_AS_CSS_MODULES.length
const cssModulesRegex = new RegExp(`(${PATHS_TO_TREAT_AS_CSS_MODULES.join('|')})`)

// Loaders for styles that need to be treated as CSS modules.
if (isUsingCSSModules) {
  /* const cssModulesLoader = [
    BASE_CSS_LOADER,
    'modules',
    'importLoaders=1',
    'localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  ].join('&') */
/*  webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'css-loader',
  query: {
    modules: true,
    importLoaders: 1 ,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  }
  }) */
  webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: cssModulesRegex,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      { loader: 'css-loader',
      query: {
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1 ,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      } },
      {loader: 'postcss-loader'},
      {
        loader: "sass-loader",
        query: {
            includePaths: [paths.client('styles')]
        }
      },  
    ]
  })

  webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: cssModulesRegex,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      { loader: 'css-loader',
      query: {
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1 ,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      } },
      {loader: 'postcss-loader'}
    ]
  })
}

// Loaders for files that should not be treated as CSS modules.
const excludeCSSModules = isUsingCSSModules ? cssModulesRegex : false
webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: excludeCSSModules,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    { loader: 'css-loader',
      query: {
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1 ,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      } },
      {loader: 'postcss-loader'},
    {
      loader: "sass-loader",
      query: {
          includePaths: [paths.client('styles')]
      }
    },  
  ]
})
webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: excludeCSSModules,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    { loader: 'css-loader',
      query: {
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1 ,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      } },
      {loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: () => {
         return [
            require('cssnano')({
              autoprefixer: true
            })
          ]
        }
      }
      }
  ]
})

// ------------------------------------
// Style Configuration
// ------------------------------------
/* webpackConfig.plugins.postcss.push({
        require('cssnano')().
        require('autoprefixer')({add: true,
          remove: true,
          browsers: ['last 2 versions']}),
          discardComments: {
            removeAll: true
          },
          discardUnused: false,
          mergeIdents: false,
          reduceIdents: false,
          safe: true,
          sourcemap: true
        }) */
/* webpackConfig.plugins.push ({
  'sass-loader':{
  includePaths: paths.client('styles'),
  sourceMap:true
  }
}) */
/* webpackConfig.plugins.push({
  'postcss-cssnano':{
  }

//includePaths: paths.client('styles')
}) */
webpackConfig.plugins = [
  cssnano({
    preset: 'default',
    autoprefixer: {
      add: true,
      remove: true,
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    },
    discardComments: {
      removeAll: true
    },
    discardUnused: false,
    mergeIdents: false,
    reduceIdents: false,
    safe: true,
    sourcemap: true
  })
]

// File loaders
/* eslint-disable */
// Images
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
  test    : /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
  loader  : 'url-loader',
  options : {
    limit : 8192
  }
});

// Fonts
// ------------------------------------
;[
  ['woff', 'application/font-woff'],
  ['woff2', 'application/font-woff2'],
  ['otf', 'font/opentype'],
  ['ttf', 'application/octet-stream'],
  ['eot', 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'],
  ['svg', 'image/svg+xml'],
].forEach((font) => {
  const extension = font[0];
  const mimetype  = font[1];
  webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
    test    : new RegExp(`\\.${extension}$`),
    loader  : 'url-loader',
    options : {
      name  : 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
      limit : 10000,
      mimetype
    }
  });
});
/* eslint-enable */

/* Configure Webpack to ignore dojo modules */
/* webpackConfig.module.externals = [
  function(context, request, callback) {
    if (/^dojo/.test(request) ||
        /^dojox/.test(request) ||
        /^dijit/.test(request) ||
        /^esri/.test(request)
    ) {
        return callback(null, "amd " + request);
    }
    callback();
  }
]; */

// ------------------------------------
// Finalize Configuration
// ------------------------------------
// when we don't know the public path (we know it only when HMR is enabled [in development]) we
// need to use the extractTextPlugin to fix this issue:
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133808/webpack-ots-parsing-error-loading-fonts/34133809#34133809
if (!__DEV__) {
  debug('Apply ExtractTextPlugin to CSS loaders.')
  webpackConfig.module.loaders.filter((loader) =>
    loader.loaders && loader.loaders.find((name) => /css/.test(name.split('?')[0]))
  ).forEach((loader) => {
    const [first, ...rest] = loader.loaders
    loader.loader = ExtractTextPlugin.extract(first, rest.join('!'))
    Reflect.deleteProperty(loader, 'loader')
  })

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[contenthash].css', {
      allChunks: true
    })
  )
}

export default webpackConfig
```

> Sample Errors
>   ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--2-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./node_modules/flexboxgrid2/flexboxgrid2.css
>   Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: D:\current
>   project\DOCTC16\doctc\node_modules\flexboxgrid2
>       at config.load.then (D:\current project\DOCTC16\doctc\node_modules\postcss-load-config\src\index.js:55:15)
>       at  @ ./node_modules/flexboxgrid2/flexboxgrid2.css 4:14-109 @ ./node_modules/react-flexbox-grid/lib/classNames.js @
>   ./node_modules/react-flexbox-grid/lib/components/Grid.js @
>   ./node_modules/react-flexbox-grid/lib/index.js @
>   ./src/routes/Devices/components/swapdevice.js @
>   ./src/routes/Devices/containers/SwapContainer.js @
>   ./src/routes/Devices/containers/DevicesContainer.js @
>   ./src/routes/Devices/containers/DevicesPage.js @
>   ./src/routes/Devices/index.js @ ./src/routes/index.js @ ./src/main.js
>   @ multi babel-polyfill whatwg-fetch ./src/main.js
>   webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://10.203.214.174:3000/__webpack_hmr

Comment: Do you have `postcss.config.js` ?

Comment: I found a work around, the post css loader should be loaded from external file
I created the config file separately and its working. but it is throwing Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core/utils/environment.js' error now

Comment: Never mind, got the solution. The file was misplaced.